# Test for a Poisson process with a statistic related to clustering

Tags: goodness-of-fit, poisson-process

I have a dataset of a realisation of a one-dimensional point process. I would like to test for a Poisson process with some statistics connected with clustering. I would like to provide a size effect that reflects the absence of clustering.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-dimensional Poisson process (assuming constant intensity), the interarrival times have an exponential distributio9n. So just test for an exponential distribution (make a qq-plot against the exponential).

For other ideas (from the spatial domain) look at tag [ripley-k](/questions/tagged/ripley-k)

Comment: Thank you very much! I can definitely do that, but the problem with the goodness of fit test is that I cannot think of the proper size effect. Given a big enough dataset, I will definitely reject the null hypothesis, so I thought it would be great to report a meaningful size effect. The K-S test statistic in this sense is poorly interpretable, so I'm asking for a more clear one. 

P.S Another option I can think of is to test the data against a more complicated point process (for example, Cox) and conclude that the complexity has little effect on the likelihood.